# Create the list with limited elements inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to create ul with a limit of 5 li's inside. If it goes more then 5 elements - create new ul with the same limitations. And so on and on. Here is the start point I made:

```js
$(function(){
var $container = $('.container'),
  el = 5,
  i;  
 newUl = $('<ul />')
  for(i=0; i < el; i++){
   $container.append(newUl)
   $('<li />', { html : i }).appendTo(newUl)   
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.wrapper {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.wrapper .container {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.wrapper ul {
  background: #c0c0c0;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  font-size: 0;
}
.wrapper ul:nth-of-type(odd) {
  direction: rtl;
}
.wrapper ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  text-align: center;
  direction: rtl;
}

.status {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper"> 
 <div class="container"> 
  
 </div>
</div>
<div class="status"></div>
```

Any advices how to do this?

Comment: You need a way to identify the total number of `li`s that you want to split into 5's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the modulus operator `%` to determine when you have reached the max, and then you need to create a new jQuery for your new ul, and append it.

```js
$(function(){
  var $container = $('.container'),
   el = 10,
   max = 5,
   i;  
  var newUl;
  for(i=0; i < el; i++){
   if(i%max==0) {
     newUl = $('<ul/>');
     $container.append(newUl);
   }
   $('<li />', { html : i }).appendTo(newUl)   
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.wrapper {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.wrapper .container {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.wrapper ul {
  background: #c0c0c0;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  font-size: 0;
}
.wrapper ul:nth-of-type(odd) {
  direction: rtl;
}
.wrapper ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  text-align: center;
  direction: rtl;
}

.status {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper"> 
 <div class="container"> 
  
 </div>
</div>
<div class="status"></div>
```

Comment: This really isn't a time to use modulus. It's tempting to try to solve the problem as a human analyzing this as a math problem. But unless the user wants to display the number it is unimportant (and more likely to introduce an error). Splice is a better answer because it solves the problem using the existing tools and is better code (when you debug this code years from now the math is a worse problem to solve than splice). Also the CSS is unrelated to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite following your example, so forgive me that I've just started fresh here. The first loop and the `12` on line 2 is just to generate a list of fake data to work with. Test it with 0, less than 5, multiples of 5, and 1+ a multiple of 5 just to make sure it works.

```
var items = [];
for(var i=0; i<12; i++) {
    items.push("item " + i.toString());
}
var subItems = items.splice(0, 5);
var div = $("<div>").get(0);
while(subItems.length > 0) {
    var ul = $("<ul>").get(0);
    div.appendChild(ul);
    for(var i=0; i<subItems.length; i++) {
        ul.appendChild( $("<li>").text(subItems[i]).get(0) );
    }
    subItems = items.splice(0, 5);
}
```

You can paste this into the console to see the results. Just add `console.log(div)` at the end.

This will create a div with n number of ul tags, each having 5 li's (or less depending on the data)

Change line 6 to point to your div tag. And I'm not sure we can tell from your example where the data is supposed to come from so you'll need to change items and line 11 accordingly.

Comment: Data comes from JSON. Thanks for the clues. I appreciate that.